# Le blanc lumineux, en tant que couleur

Tags: vocabulaire, latin, lexique, ancien-français

Le latin a le mot "candidus" pour désigner un "blanc lumineux". Ce mot existe aussi dans d'autres langues. "Cannaid" en gallois, etc...

Y a-t-il en français ou vieux français, ou dans un dialecte français, un mot qui désignerait cette couleur, ou c'est simplement une couleur qui n'existe pas en français?

Edit: suite à la réponse qui confond les 2 sens de "candidus":

> Candidus:
>   1. (of light, of source of light, etc) Bright, radiant.
>   2. (of colour) White. The opposite of black.

Source: *Oxford Latin Dictionary,* Oxford at the Clarendon, 1968: Oxford Latin Dictionary,

page 264, consultable sur Google book.

Donc, Oxford, c'est comme pour Gaffiot, ce n'est pas du tout fiable, c'est ça?
Et Candidus n'est pas une couleur....

S'il n'y avait qu'Oxford et Gaffiot, mais Valbuena, Jeannot, Georges, Calonghi, de Miguel, disent la même chose. Ce mot **a plusieurs sens** (comme certains mots français décrivant des couleurs), et est aussi utilisé en tant que couleur.

Donc tout le monde se trompe?

Pareil pour le mot "color".

Oxford Latin dictionary:

> Color.
>   1. Colour as a property of physical object, also, a particular color.
>   2. Colouring matter, pigment.
>   3. The colour of the skin.

Si le mot "color" ne veut pas dire "couleur", je ne sais pas ce qu'il peut vouloir dire.

> I examine the frequencies of all potentially-basic color terms in the extant texts of five authors chosen to represent a spanof about six hundred years: Plautus, Cato the Elder, Cicero, Seneca, and Saint Jerome. My
>   initial hypothesis was that niger was displacing ater as the basic Black term; a similar shift was occurring *as candidus displaced albus as the default White term*; (...) In Plautus, candidus and albus formed an equal percentage of
>   total color vocabulary, and displayed only slightly divergent trends, which may reflect **the use of albus for “matte white” and candidus for “shiny white.**”

Source: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1665/f2df373ac75b6f10e9ebc4918378d0c40c38.pdf

> (...)Le blanc était nommé en latin par albus (« blanc mat ») et candidus
>   (« blanc éclatant »). Si ces termes se retrouvent dans albescent, aube, aubade,
>   aubépine (« épine blanche »), etc. ainsi que dans candide, candeur, candidat
>   , le terme blanc, générique exprimant la blancheur, est issu du germanique
>   blank («brillant, clair ») et aurait été employé par les soldats germains pour
>   qualifier l’éclat des armes ou la robe des chevaux

https://gerflint.fr/Base/Italie4/mollarddesfour.pdf
"Les mots de couleur - de A Mollard-Desfour ( linguiste, lexicographe, sémiologue au CNRS)  [Sa notice](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annie_Mollard-Desfour).

Comment: **Candeur** emploi en ancien français voir définition dans le lexique de [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/lexique-godefroy/cand) et exemples dans le dictionnaire de [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/cand), traduction  dans [Cotgrave](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/cotgrave/cand), etc. DHLF : « Du lat. *candor*, blancheur éclatante [...] Le sens propre de « blancheur » « clarté » s'est effacé au 17e s. devant le sens figuré et moral de pureté ».

Comment: Ce commentaire répond parfaitement, et mérite d'être transformé en réponse.

Comment: Je dirais bien si j'en crois Pline qui les décrit dans son Histoire Naturelle que ce *candidus* n'est pas vraiment le nom d'une *couleur* au sens contemporain de *couleur*. De *couleur* proprement dite pour obtenir cet effet, Pline en décrit 4 ou 5 dont la fameuse *Céruse* qui nous est restée sous ce nom et divers autres dont le désormais très interdit *blanc de plomb*. Il nous reste encore aujourd'hui le *blanc de Meudon*.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. "Candidus" est un nom de couleur, car on le retrouve utilisé comme adjectif "toga candida" est extrêmement célèbre par exemple, et désigne les toges d'un blanc lumineux dont se revêtaient les candidats au sénat.

Comment: @aCOSwt Il me semble (semble car tu es latiniste, pas moi), qu'en latin il y avait 2 mots là où nous n'en avons plus qu'un. *Alba* pour le blanc mat, et *candida* pour le blanc brillant (de même *niger* et *alter* pour le noir). De nos jours il n'y a plus qu'en graphisme qu'on oppose mat/brillant et la langue courante depuis le bas-latin n'a gardé que *blancus* pour la dénomination de la couleur. Céruse et blanc d'Espagne (plus courant que Meudon) que tu mentionnes réfèrent à des pigments (c.a.d substances) et pas à des nuances basées sur l'effet produit par le réfléchissement de la lumière).

Comment: La *toga candida* était la toge « blanchie à la craie » (traduction qu'on trouve fréquemment) qui effectivement distinguait à l'époque classique le « candidat » à une élection, et d'où est issu le terme de candidat.

Comment: *Quid ergo istic **duo** colores faciunt **lucis atque umbrae**, cum innumerabilium ratio redenda sit ?* Ce n'est évidemment qu'une question. Mais elle est d'Ovide. Après... OUI! J'ai été excessif en écrivant *"n'est pas une couleur"* au sens ou j'ai (par erreur) délibérément ignoré la demi-douzaine de mots d'un vocabulaire qui permet juste de se comprendre approximativement. MyBad donc!

Comment: Je répondrai donc à votre question autrement : Non, il n'existe pas en français contemporain de **couleur** correspondant au *candidus* latin et cela pour la bonne raison que ***couleur*** et ***color*** ne recouvrent pas le même concept.

Comment: Français contemporain... ou ancien.

Comment: @LaureSO-Écoute-nous Petite remarque sur le commentaire n°5: tu parles des deux mots latins pour noir, c'est _niger_ et _ater_, tu as mis un 'l' en trop

Comment: @Steph Merci du rectificatif  !

Comment: Le DHLF confirme ce que dit @aCOSwt sur le sens du latin color (teint du visage). Le DCLF  consacre 10 pages au mot « couleur » et on voit que le mot pour désigner ce qu'on appelle « des couleurs » (« » pour rappeler que les couleurs ne sont pas présentes sur les objets mais sont des constructions du cerveau) n'a commencé à être employé dans son sens actuel en français que vers le 11e s. Dans la [chanson de Roland](micmap.org/dicfro/search/glossaire-chanson-de-roland/culur) il est encore pratiquement toujours (a une exception près) utilisé pour parler de la couleur de la peau.

Comment: Donc, Oxford se plante? Encore une fois, les latinisants savent qu'un mot latin a souvent plusieurs sens (encore plus qu'en français). Ici, c'est un mot avec plusieurs sens. Comme en français, il y a le sens premier, et les autres acceptations. J'ai suffisamment cité de dictionnaires qui font foi, comme Oxford, comme Lewis & Short, comme les dictionnaires en italien et en espagnol, qui sont tous d'accord sur la polysémie du mot, et sur l'un des sens pour couleur et candidus.

Comment: D'autre part, il ne faut pas confondre le latin tardif et le latin classique. En latin, il ne faut jamais consulter qu'un seul ouvrage, on compare les ouvrages entre eux (ce qu'on ne fait pas forcément en français). Les références en latin pour le monde anglo-saxon,sont équivalent au Littré ou du Grévisse chez nous, sont le Lewis & Short, and l'Oxford. Chez nous, il y a Gaffiot et Bailly. Dire qu'un des grands dictionnaires se plante, je n'ai jamais entendu cela dans mes cours de latin!

Comment: Moi j'abandonne, si vous voulez dire qu'Oxford et Gaffiot et Lewis & Short et les autres cités, et les professeurs d'universités cités en PDF, sont tous des abrutis et des incapables, et qu'ils racontent n'importe quoi. Allez-y. Mais alors Littré, Robert, etc, aussi. Et dans ce cas, ça ne sert plus à rien de citer aucune référence sur ce site!

Comment: Latin SE: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/9495/how-to-say-striped-in-latin/9497#9497 "toga candida et nigra sulcatim. A toga, furrowed black and white" Mais c'est probablement tous des incompétents aussi sur Latin SE?https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1462/help-with-latin-translation-from-a-17th-century-ecclesiastical-latin-book "De colorum mixtione, qui differunt, ex varia eorum commixtione omnis fere generis colores fieri posse existimant.

Those who discuss mixing different colors think that a color of almost any kind can come from a varying mixture of them.

Comment: De toute façon, je pourrais mettre 999999 références des plus grandes universités du monde, j'aurais toujours tort, parce que vous avez décidé que j'avais tort (vous m'avez dans le nez visiblement). Vous sélectionnez seulement ce qui va à l'encontre du reste, et fermez les yeux sur tout ce qui va dans le sens de la question. C'est comme si je sélectionnais un des sens pour un mot dans un dictionnaire et que je niais les autres utilisations du mot, parce qu'un dictionnaire ne le mentionne pas, même si tous les autres le font.

Comment: " n'a commencé à être employé dans son sens actuel en français que vers le 11e s. Dans la [chanson de Roland]: Ceci concerne le français, et non le latin. En latin, il suffit de faire une recherche ici, et traduire les phrases en latin, pour s'apercevoir que c'est faux: https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=color

Answer (score 3):

<sup>NDaCOSwt: Toute la réponse à cette question repose sur le lexique qu'on décide de prendre en référence.
Relativement à une langue morte, le lexique est établi à postériori sur la base d'un corpus fini.
Relativement à la couleur, on distinguera trois lexiques, l'usuel (établi d'après l'étude des textes en prose), le poétique (assez... flou et incertain par nature), les lexiques techniques (le vocabulaire des peintres évidemment mais aussi celui des naturalistes et celui des... médecins!)</sup>

---

**A1/ Pour ce qui est de l'usuel... le *color* latin... n'est pas une *couleur*!**

Cette affirmation qui fera sans doute frémir le traducteur adepte des solutions de facilité est corroborée par l'étude du lexique technique de la médecine qui, parce que la couleur n'est pas leur spécialité, se servent des termes usuels pour décrire l'état des patients.

Le terme de français usuel le plus adapté à la traduction du *color* usuel latin est sans conteste : le **teint**.

**Et au premier chef le teint de la peau**(1) puisque le verbe dérivé *colorari* signifiera d'abord... : *bronzer*!

Attesté ainsi par de très nombreux auteurs classiques dont l'immanquable Cicéron (*cum in sole ambulem, natura fit ut colorer*), lequel Cicéron est probablement responsable de son premier emploi, par métaphore en rhétorique, entre beaucoup d'autres :

*Urbanitate quadam quasi colorata oratio* qu'on a d'ailleurs été bien avisé de traduire par : *Un discours pour ainsi dire **teinté** d'une certaine urbanité*

---

<sup>1 : Faut-il rappeler que le grec *χρῶμα* est construit sur *χρῶs* (la peau) et devra d'ailleurs être traduit... quand on l'aura inventé... par le français *carnation*</sup>

---

**A.2/ Toujours dans l'usuel... le *candidus (a,um)* latin, adjectif... n'a rien non plus à voir avec le nom d'une *couleur***

Pour ne citer que Virgile (exemplatif des usuels) on le trouverait au sens de *éblouissant / radieux / brillant / lumineux* qualifiant tout autre chose que du blanc.

Il est par ailleurs toujours (à ma connaissance) employé en tant qu'adjectif. Usuellement, le nom d'une couleur est un substantif dont l'adjectif correspondant dérive.

Et puis le principe de l'usuel est bien d'être compris par tous. Et la meilleure façon de procéder en matière de couleurs est d'emprunter le substantif à un objet connu exemplatif. Ainsi le latin usuel connaît-il le (rouge-)sang, le (rouge-)feu, le (bleu-)ciel...(2) et bien évidemment **le blanc**... : ***album***! (3)

---

<sup>2 : *cum ex ipsis rebus vocabula colorum mutuatur et "igneum" aliquid dicit et "flammeum" et "sanguineum" et "croceum" et "ostrinum" et "aureum"...* (Aulu-Gelle)</sup>

<sup>3 : D'ailleurs En fait de *couleur* blanche proprement dite, album (et dérivés) est aussi souvent employé par opposition au noir. Ainsi Caton nomme-t-il l'oliva nigra et... par opposition *oliva alba* l'olive que nous disons aujourd'hui *verte*... mais en fait juste... non noire.</sup>

---

**B/ Le langage des poétes.**

Toujours bien difficile à traduire... on peut néanmoins assurer que le poète est d'abord sensible et attaché à rendre des **gradations de l'intensité lumineuse.**

On peut le lire dans la citation faite en commentaires dans l'OP (4) et empruntée à un Ovide bien embarrassé pour décrire l'arc en ciel au moyen des deux seules *colores* : La lumière et l'ombre!
On trouverait la même chose dit autrement chez Sénèque.

---

<sup>4: *Quid ergo istic duo colores faciunt lucis atque umbrae, cum innumerabilium ratio redenda sit ?*</sup>

---

NDaCOSwt : Je réalise que le développement de ce sujet m'emmène très loin et possiblement OT pour FSE. Je ne l'ai entrepris que pour justifier de ma réponse lapidaire en commentaire de l'OP.
Je le continuerai ou non en fonction de l'accueil.

FULL STOP donc! Suite aux commentaires, il me semble inutile de persister dans une direction osant suggérer que Cicéron, Ovide, Aulu-Gelle, Virgile, Caton, Pline, Sénèque... connaîtraient le latin très mieux que Gaffiot!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101433/discussion-on-answer-by-acoswt-le-blanc-lumineux-en-tant-que-couleur).

Answer (score -1):

Je pense que j'ai trouvé quelque chose qui s'en rapproche.

Comme le disait très justement Laure, dans les commentaires, il est marquant de voir que le latin avait 2 adjectifs de couleur, et que le français n'en a retenu qu'un.

Ceci s'explique sans doute par le fait qu'en français on utilise une périphrase poétique:

d'un blanc virginal, d'un blanc immaculé...

Ce type de blanc n'est pas spécialement lumineux, mais d'un blanc de neige/d'un blanc de neige, l'est.

C'est là que j'ai trouvé un adjectif, qui peut être à la fois un adjectif qui désigne l'aspect, mais peut aussi être utilisé comme adjectif de couleur, comme par exemple "brun".

C'est *nivéen*.

> Nivéen (adj. rare) : Qui ressemble à la neige. Ou est blanc comme neige.

Je me demande si dans certaines régions il ne devient pas "nivéal".

Il y avait aussi "candeur", dans son acceptation ancienne, très justement trouvé par Laure, mais je crois qu'il évoque plutôt un blanc pur que lumineux.

Comment: Peut-être que la dernière phrase pourrait être complété par « malgré ce que disent [Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/cand) blancheur : *clarté* et [Cotgrave](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/cotgrave/cand) *A bright or shining whiteness*.

Comment: [Nivéal](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/niv%C3%A9al)(du latin neige) ne s'applique pas spécifiquement à la couleur mais désigne tout rapport avec la neige. On peut l'associer à un adj. de couleur (blancheur nivéale) mais **seul** ce n'est pas un nom de couleur. [Nivéen](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/niv%C3%A9en), lui peut s'employer comme adjectif de couleur mais comme il n'est apparu qu'au 19e s. il était, comme nivéal, inconnu en vieux français, aucun des deux n'a un emploi spécifiquement régional.

Comment: C'est exactement que j'ai mis dans ma réponse (relisez). Je n'ai pas non plus dit que c'était un nom de couleur, mais la définition "blanc comme la neige" s'en rapproche. Si vous avez mieux, allez-y. C'est le mieux que j'ai pu trouver pour l'instant. Si j'ai posé cette question ici, c'est que la réponse est plutôt dure à trouver.

Comment: Rien n'empêche, d'après cette définition d'utiliser "nivéen" comme une couleur (avec un nom, pas seul, donc la définition n'est pas parfaite, mais dans certains contextes, c'est équivalent), une écharpe nivéenne, toujours d'après cette définition, peut très bien désigner une écharpe blanche comme la neige. Comme ici on sait que ce ne sera pas en rapport avec la texture de la neige, c'est la seule acceptation possible. Donc, ça le fait très bien dans ce contexte, en attendant de trouver mieux, si vous avez.

Comment: D'ailleurs, c'est pareil pour certains adjectifs (souvent ceux décrivant une texture) qui ne sont pas primairement des noms de couleurs, mais peuvent être utilisés comme tels, ils décrivent soit une texture, soit une couleur, suivant le contexte. Par exemple caséeux. Ayant fait des sciences je peux vous assurer qu'il s'agit à la fois, suivant le contexte, d'une texture ou d'une couleur (ou plutôt d'une fourchette de couleurs, comme on dirait les rouges), certaines couleurs ne sont pas toujours déterminées comme rougeâtre, etc...

Comment: Ce qu'on appelle "couleur" est très subjectif. Les gens sur ce fil semblent penser que c'est quelque chose de statique et de donné une fois pour toute. Mais ce que vous n'appelez pas couleur, demain, peut devenir le nom d'une couleur. Il suffit qu'un nuancier soit publié, et qu'il remporte un certain succès, avec le nom "Scarlette" pour un certain nom de rouge, et cela devient un nom de couleur. Les couleurs se somment par analogie. Il n'y a rien comme un nom de "couleur" objectif, les noms de couleur sont des habitudes, des conventions, sur lesquelles plusieurs personnes tombent d'accord.

Comment: Du moment qu'on peut très bien comprendre à partir de la définition, de quelle teinte on parle, et c'est le cas de "nivéen", c'est une couleur, d'autant plus que c'est précisé dans sa définition "d'un blanc de neige", donc ce n'est pas un emploi nouveau.

Comment: Et encore un downvote pour rien.

Comment: Quand y en a qui ont la haine, ils ont la haine.